# PHP not inserting into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data into the database table I have copied the code PHPmyadmin gives me to insert data into the database. I have also researcher other similar problems to this and found that i have been using back ticks I have not been using reserved words that could have stopped this working.
The code is as follows:

```
<?php
// Connect to MYSQL
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", 
"Test_downtime");
if (!$connect) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n";
$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `Test_downtime`.`Downtime` (`ID`, 
`Server_Name`, `Average_downtime`, `Last_downtime`) VALUES (NULL, \'Test\', 
\'3224\', \'2222\')");
if (mysqli_query($sql)) {
  echo $servername . "has been updated";
} 
else{
  echo "Error: " ."<br>" . mysqli_error($sql);
}
?>
```

I wondered if anyone on here had any ideas as to why this is not inserting.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` need first parameter as database connection. Better use prepared statement

Comment: and you probably don't want to be escaping those inverted commas.

Comment: Don't execute query twice!!

Comment: After adding the connection to the query and removing the second query and no longer escaping the inverted commas still nothing happens

Comment: Are you getting output from this running? Specifically, is the last echo producing a message that would give a clue to whats going wrong?

Comment: Its only echoing Error: then not displaying the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_query( connection , query ) needs two paramenters

```
<?php

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password","Test_downtime");

        if (!$connect) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }else
        {
            echo "Connected successfully\n";
        }


    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `Downtime` (ID, 
    Server_Name, Average_downtime, Last_downtime) VALUES (NULL, 'Test', 
    3224,2222); ");

    if ($sql == true) 
    {
      echo $servername . "has been updated";
    } 
    else
    {
      echo "Error: " ."<br>" . mysqli_error($sql);
    }
    ?>
```